# WSO 2 App Factory Issue Tracker Integration

Tags: jenkins, wso2, jira

I would like to have an Issue Tracker working in a continuous integration environment, I have tried the App Factory Platform on the cloud and I like it very much, however I have read [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF100/Adding+Tests+and+Tracking+Issues) that: 
*" At the moment, issues are created and managed externally to the App Factory portal. "* so: what is the point of adding an Issue Tracker to App Factory? and also: What are the exact differences between having an Issue Tracker integrated with App Factory rather than Jenkins? Should I have the Issue Tracker integrated with both?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The document that you are quoting is outdated. Indeed initially Issue Tracker was a separate tool that you would open in a new window, etc.

Now it is fully integrated and is just a tab inside application properties, with full context on your application team, branches, and so on.

You can see that yourself both in App Factory and in the cloud version - [App Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud/) - that you are using: just go into any of your apps, and click Issue Tracker tab on the left-hand side.

Comment: Thank you very much, so, to become clear, what you are telling me is that the integration between App Factory and an Issue Tracker is only a facade inside AppFactory? Is it possible that for example: if a Jenkins build fails then the App Factory could be able to create an issue automatically?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality in the product (automatic tickets on build failures) but I guess potentially this could be implemented via APIs. Issue Tracker is made replaceable so on-premise customers could use JIRA or something instead of the built-in option.